# how to get the data from enom api in laravel using controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

By passing this link

> https://resellertest.enom.com/interface.asp?command=check&sld=enom&tld=com&responsetype=xml&uid=resellid&pw=resellpw

How can I get the below data in laravel using controller.

```
<interface-response>
<DomainName>enom.com</DomainName>
<RRPCode>211</RRPCode>
<RRPText>Domain not available</RRPText>
<Command>CHECK</Command>
<APIType>API.NET</APIType>
<Language>eng</Language>
<ErrCount>0</ErrCount>
<ResponseCount>0</ResponseCount>
<MinPeriod>1</MinPeriod>
<MaxPeriod>10</MaxPeriod>
<Server>sjl1vwresell_t</Server>
<Site>eNom</Site>
<IsLockable>True</IsLockable>
<IsRealTimeTLD>True</IsRealTimeTLD>
<TimeDifference>+8.00</TimeDifference>
<ExecTime>0.328</ExecTime>
<Done>true</Done>
<TrackingKey>1f5b6d77-f715-42af-94a2-a30e0a40f847</TrackingKey>
<RequestDateTime>5/2/2018 12:58:22 AM</RequestDateTime>
<debug/>
</interface-response>
```

How to pass the url to controller and display the data in view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this library:
https://github.com/ixudra/curl

In your controller:

```
use Ixudra\Curl\Facades\Curl;

public function test()
{
    $response = Curl::to('https://resellertest.enom.com/interface.asp?command=check&sld=enom&tld=com&responsetype=xml&uid=resellid&pw=resellpw')
        ->get();
    //dd($response); //check if we are getting a response
    return view('index', array(
        'response' => $response,
    ));
}
```

Data Dump `dd($response);` will look like this:

[image]

**Answer to a different question from the comment:**

**1st** Your form should route to the method in your controller, and form (POST method) input should have:

```
<input type="text" name="sld">
<input type="text" name="tld">
...
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value"{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

**2nd** Capture the form request to a method in your controller:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function test(Request $request)
    {
        $sld = $request['sld'];
        $tld = $request['tld'];
        //if you want, initialize more variables here...

        $response = Curl::to('https://resellertest.enom.com/interface.asp?command=check&sld='. $sld .'&tld='. 
$tld .'&responsetype=xml&uid=resellid&pw=resellpw')
            ->get();
        //dd($response); //check if we are getting a response
        return view('index', array(
            'response' => $response,
        ));
    }
```

Comment: Thank You. It works good, But the data is not getting printed in my view. When I use this  dd($response) I'm getting result as $response1. Please suggest me a solution for this.

Comment: can you please suggest me how to pass the array value in blade file. I was passed the array value in my blade like this "dd($response)" but i didn't get the data. Please suggest me some solutions

Comment: you should comment that line `//dd($response);` This code is only to check id the data is getting fetched.
You need to pass the `$response` variable in the view. I have already written the code on my answer.

Comment: Check the answer, I have updated it again. The view name should be "index.blade.php" and you can print the data in the view using `{{ $response }}`

Comment: How to pass the form variable in the url please suggest me the solutions. For Example i need to pass the variable in the below url like 'sld' => Input::get('sld')  and 'tld' => Input::get('tld').when i submit the form i need to get the json data

https://resellertest.enom.com/interface.asp?command=check&sld=enom&tld=com&responsetype=xml&uid=resellid&pw=resellpw

please suggest me any solution